# Python initializing variable in a nested loop

Tags: python, increment, nested-loops

i want the the variable genCounter to reset to zero when the iteration of the inner loops has completed. however it returns the first value of genreSet and does not go farther to increment the genCounter variable. kawa is a genrator object. Thanks in advance..

```
kawa = self.getFile()
genList = []
genCounter = 0
for gen in self.genreSet:
  print(gen)
  if genCounter == 0 :
    for ids, row in enumerate(kawa):
      self.genres = row['genres']
      self.genresList = self.genres.split('|')
      for n in self.genresList:
        if gen == n:
          genCounter+=1
  print(genCounter)
  genCounter=0
```

and this is the result

```
Documentary
2471
Sci-Fi
0
War
0
Horror
0
Musical
0
Children
0
Mystery
0
Drama
0
IMAX
0
Action
0
Adventure
0
Fantasy
0
Crime
0
Comedy
0
(no genres listed)
0
Animation
0
Thriller
0
Romance
0
Western
0
Film-Noir
0
```

Comment: do you simply want `genCounter = 0` instead of `if genCounter == 0`?

Comment: i want 'genCounter = 0' every after the inner loop completes iteration _notice one line edit at the end_  @Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kawa is a generator object. Therefore, its becomes empty after the first call to

```
enumerate(kawa)
```

If you replace the first line of code with

```
kawa = tuple(self.getFile())
```

Then it probably will work. (Or at least yield a different bug ;)

Comment: Thank you just perfect indeed @Pete

Comment: i do versions of that bug all the time. you just get better at spotting it